# Do I need to pay for a github account in order to download the Tapku Library?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, github, tapku

I need a good looking calender for my iOS application, and I heard Tapku was the best option. However, it looked like I had to pay for a github account to even load the Tapku library.

Also, if it is not necessary for me to pay anything, then how exactly do I download it and put it into my xcode project.

**I have in fact seen the instructions for downloading the library but they made no sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

Github accounts are free unless you want to host private git repositories. But you don't need a github account to `clone` or download a public github repo. Just click the "zip" link to download a zip or use git to clone the repository like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary.git
```

(you need to have git installed in order to use git from the command line).

Comment: where git clone to in mac